# Listing courses to be completed along with past courses

Tags: research-undergraduate

A question on a research program application states the following: "Please list a few courses you took that will be relevant for the [RESEARCH PROGRAM]". (They also ask for grades) A transcript with 1st semester grades is being submitted, but the deadline for application is March 1st, meaning that although 2nd semester courses will not be finished, I will be well into them.

With this in mind, should I include 2nd semester courses too (obviously without grades), or just 1st semester? I do not know where else on the application I can indicate that I am currently taking those courses (unless my transcript as of March 1 has courses in progress).

I apologize if this question is silly, as it is essentially an interpretation of a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is normal to list things that you are in the middle of, eg when you apply for a job you include your current job. The key point is that you must be careful to **make it clear you have not completed the courses**. Sometimes the form will make that essentially impossible, but requiring, say, a completion date that's in the past. In that case it's perhaps best to contact the people you are applying to and ask their advice.

Comment: It may be that they are specifically looking for completed courses for that particular question, but there is somewhere else where you can give other relevant information such as the courses you are now taking.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I took the wording of the question to indicate that was not the case here. I can't remember ever seeing a form that was structure that way.